# Cant transfer more than 2.1 GBs to my android phone from computer why is that?

Tags: backup, file-transfer, xiaomi

I am trying to transfer 14 GB folder from my laptop to my phone using USB cable but the copy stops at 2.1 GB and doesn't give any error message, is there a way I can transfer the whole folder?

Comment: Do you copy the files to internal storage or to an "external" SD-card (non-adopted)?

Comment: better use adb push

Comment: @Robert internal storage

Comment: @alecxs dont know how to do that

Comment: Then this is strange, because MTP should have a limit of max 4GB per file and internal storage should be formatted with a file-system that should allow the same size or even more. Your laptop is running Windows? Which version?

Comment: enable [developer options](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/124917), enable usb-debugging, connect phone, install [ADB drivers](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb), extract [platform-tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools), (optional) set [path](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm), open cmd.exe, type: *adb.exe push "C:\path\to\dir" /sdcard*